# how to make the file saved with the date name?

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

I wrote a bash script that archives a file from a directory

```
  #!/bin/bash
    echo "1-archieve"
    echo "2-exit"
    read doing
    case $doing in
    1)
    echo "choose directory"
    read path
    echo "choose name file"
    read name
    tar -cvzf $name $path;;
    2)
    exit 0;;
    *)
    echo "error"
    esac
```

but I need it to save a new file with a name that contains the date. for example 28_11_2022_14-46. I read that the **date** command is responsible for this. but how to make the file saved with the date name?

Comment: There a tons of date examples here, which one did you try ?

Comment: something along the lines `name=${name}_\`date +%XXXX\``. as for what you want exactly as +%XXXX read `man date`

Comment: @GillesQuenot i have this command date '+%H-%M_%d-%m-%y' but I don't know how to add it to the code so that it works

Comment: You need bash _command substitution_

Comment: @GillesQuenot completely rewrite the code or what?

Comment: This is not clear what exactly you want to do. I don't see `date` attemps in your code. You should edit your question to add failed attempt in your code